# Node.js, Express.js doesn't send file to client

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express

I'm trying to send a gif to the client to use later in CSS. The console logs give me a 404 not found for the gif. It is in the public directory.

### Server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var express = require('express');
var peopleCount = 0;


express().use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
  });
```

### CSS

```
span {
            background:url('public/gif.gif');
            background-repeat:repeat-x;
            background-position:0 0;
            text-align:center;
            color:transparent;
            -webkit-background-clip:text;
            -moz-background-clip:text;
            background-clip:text;
            -webkit-text-fill-color:transparent;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 20px;
    }
```

The server sends the `index.html` file fine, but not the `gif.gif`

Comment: change in your CSS `background:url('public/gif.gif');` to `background:url('gif.gif');`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

instead of

```
express().use(express.static('public'));
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, `public/gif.gif` is a relative reference, so this will look for the file at `<window location>/public/gif.gif`. Assuming you want this to reference the `<root>/public/gif.gif`, use an absolute reference (notice the leading `/`):

`background:url('/public/gif.gif');`

In addition, the static directories should be bound to the app instance, and should specify a name to be used when calling to the server:

`app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

in the above example, the `__dirname + /public` directory in your project would be located at `/public` when making calls to the server.

Comment: It still says "cannot GET public/gif.gif" in the console. Do you know why it might not still work?

Comment: Did you change the reference to `/public/gif.gif` and not `public/gif.gif`?